# Как обработать событие прокрутки ScrollBar в FlowLayoutPanel?

Tags: c#, winforms

В общем, у меня в **FlowLayoutPanel** есть несколько RichTextBox, идущих сверху-вниз. Я хочу обработать событие прокрутки ScrollBar (который уже есть в элементе FlowLayoutPanel), чтобы отобразить подсказку, на какой RichTextBox сейчас смотрят. Но как вообще выделить это событие прокрутки? Если это невозможно, как ещё можно реализовать данную задумку?

Comment: `myPanel.Scroll += myHandler;` А так, если тултипы нужно на текстбоксы вешать, вешайте на них, панель здесь не при чем вообще.

Comment: @aepot Спасибо! Я думал тултип сделать как в Word, где при прокрутке сразу отображается номер страницы